# printing file entity fields in a node.tpl

Tags: theming, entities, files

I have some fields in a file entity type. Now I need to print some of these fields directly in a node.tpl.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in a variety of ways. One way: in template.php, invoke `YOURTHEME_preproces_node(&$vars){}`. Inside it, do:

`if($vars['type' == 'YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE'){
   $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper("node", $vars["node"]);
   $file = $wrapper->YOUR_FILE_FIELD->value();
   ...
 }`

The `$file` variable should now contain your file object (or an array of file objects). Debug that with `print_r($file)` (or, preferably, with xdebug or another debugger) and you can add variables the `$vars` array there with:

`$vars['YOURVARIABLE'] = $file->YOURFIELD...`

which will then be available in your template as `$YOURVARIABLE`.

Comment: function miwula2015_preprocess_node(&$variables, $hook) { $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper("node", $vars["node"]);
    $file = $wrapper->field_file_image_alt_text->value(); }

brings Notice: Undefined variable: vars in MYTHEME_preprocess_node() (Zeile 61 von mytheme/template.php).
EntityMetadataWrapperException: Unknown data property field_file_image_alt_text. in EntityStructureWrapper->getPropertyInfo() (Zeile 335 von /modules/contrib/entity/includes/entity.wrapper.inc).

Should I use as field the image field of the node or e.g. the needed text field from inside the file entity?

Comment: That's because you've called it $variables.  Change that in the code, and you'll be fine. :)

Comment: I already use a preprocess_node function. So I needed to insert your code into this existing function. And it uses $variables. In case it doesn't matter I changed your code from $vars to $variables. But in this case it doesn't matter which field I use, a field from within the file entity or a (image) field of a node - in any case I get a EntityMetadataWrapperException: Unknown data property field_tile_image. in EntityStructureWrapper->getPropertyInfo()

Comment: What are you using as fieldname?  It needs to be the machine name of the field.

Comment: also, you should wrap my snippet in a conditional. I updated the answer.